# How do I show the menu button on main menu by codes?

Tags: codenameone

I have a main menu with 2 menu buttons - settingBtn and featurBtn.
vbf is the main form.

I try to click the settingBtn button in main menu, open the setting Form, do something, click the featureBtn in main menu, and open the featureForm by codes.

```
    vbf.getToolbar().openSideMenu();
    timer = UITimer.timer(200, true, ()->{
        if (vbf.getToolbar().isSideMenuShowing()){
            Component cp = vc.settingBtn;
            System.out.println(cp.getParent().getClass().getName());                
            Dialog dlg = new Dialog("settingBtn Clicked");
            dlg.showPopupDialog(cp);
            vbf.getToolbar().closeSideMenu();
            timer.cancel();
    
        }
    });
    vbf.getToolbar().openSideMenu();
    cmp = vc.featureBtn;
    Dialog dlg = new Dialog("featureBtn Clicked");
    dlg.showPopupDialog(cp);
    vbf.getToolbar().closeSideMenu();
```

The program has issues:

1. `dlg.ShowDialog(cp)` won't show at the position of the buttons if the buttons are in the main menu. It always show at the left-top of main menu.
2. The process keeps opening and closing the menu many times. I can't put all the code in UITimer. Because a UI timer is only for one time opening sidemenu.

Component Hierarchy in the inspector

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `openSideMenu()` call is asynchronous since there's an animation involved. You started that animation yet disposed the menu before it had the chance to show up.

Unfortunately, at the moment there's no way to get an event when the side menu actually shows up. However, I added the following call to `Toolbar`:  `boolean isSideMenuShowing()` as part of [this commit](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/9b34539cb0488b2038a74c5eb4de8c8f55e5624d).

You can use a timer and wait for this method to return true at which point you can continue with the logic of the walk through tour. This commit should become a part of the release on January 12th 2024.

E.g.:

```
Form hi = new Form("Hi World");
hi.getToolbar().addMaterialCommandToSideMenu("Hello", FontImage.MATERIAL_AIR, e -> {});
hi.show();
UITimer.timer(1000, true, () -> {
    Log.p("Side menu: " + hi.getToolbar().isSideMenuShowing());
});
```

Comment: I use Ant for cn1 and have refreshed cn1lib files. I can't call the `isSideMenuShowing()`
No such function.

Comment: This is a bit problematic with Ant. You can try going to maven central and downloading new Codename One and JavaSE jars from there to replace the ones in ant. We're no longer pushing updates to ant.

Comment: Would you provide documents for converting the existing project with cn1 Ant version to Maven?

Comment: I got it.
https://www.codenameone.com/blog/migrating-your-project-to-maven.html

Comment: I already converted my app from Ant to Maven. I try to run on the simulator in NetBeans IDE but go error message - `No main classes found`

Comment: There are many issues in my converted maven project. iOS build error. I sent errors to chat on cn1 website. Also I can't find Open Control Center in Run Maven right click menu,

Comment: I converted Ant to Maven by cn1 migration tool. Having many issues after migration by this tool.

Comment: Maybe I should stay in Ant. How do I download and replace the files in my Ant project to get the new functions? `isSideMenuShowing()` and toolbar.findCommandComponent(cmd)`

Comment: Find these files on maven central, download version `7.0.133`. Then find the equivalent jars in your project and replace them. Specifically you're looking for `CodenameOne.jar` and `JavaSE.jar`.

Comment: I have already migrated to Maven. `isSideMenuShowing()` doesn't work.    getToolbar().openSideMenu();     while (!getToolbar().isSideMenuShowing()){
            try{
                Thread.sleep(200);
            }catch(Exception e){
                
            }
        }
The screenshot is the same as the before.

Comment: You need to use a `UITimer` not a loop. This should run on the EDT but be deferred to later, you can't sleep on the EDT.

Comment: Would you provide some sample code for this case? I can't find UITimer in cn1 developer guide.

Comment: The following codes don't work.
        getToolbar().openSideMenu();
        UITimer.timer(2000, !getToolbar().isSideMenuShowing(), ()->{

        });
        Component cp = settingBtn;
        ul.hint_click(cp, "Click settings");     

I also tried 
        getToolbar().openSideMenu();
        UITimer.timer(2000, getToolbar().isSideMenuShowing(), ()->{

        });
        Component cp = settingBtn;
        ul.hint_click(cp, "Click settings");     
Don't work too.

Comment: The second argument is to indicate if the timer should repeat which should be true. You can then cancel the timer using the cancel method. In the lambda you need to verify that the side menu is showing and then write your code in that lambda. Not after.

Comment: It still doesn't. getToolbar().openSideMenu(); timer = UITimer.timer(200, true, ()->{ if (getToolbar().isSideMenuShowing()){ Component cp = settingBtn; ul.hint_click(cp, "Click settings"); timer.cancel(); } });  Please refer to the question.

Comment: Why would it reopen the sidemenu? The only logical explanation would be that you're invoking this code repeatedly. The showDialog call has a redundant comma. Are you sure the button instance you're referring to is non-null and has the right parent? I suggest placing a breakpoint there and inspecting the button. Check that its parent is indeed the side menu and that it is showing correctly.

Comment: I am designing an On-Boarding Flow, so I have to open the menu repeatedly. The output of System.out.println(cp.getParent().getClass().getName()); is com.codename1.ui.Container. How do I know the parent of the button is exactly the side menu? There is no function like getSideMenu() of the toolbar. To solve the second issue, can I turn off the animation of the menu during On-Boarding?

Comment: In the debugger you can invoke getParent() and look at the object IDs of the parents. You can also inspect the objects in the IDE and look at their parent objects. `System.out` won't be very useful here, can you run with the proper IDE debugger? It's very useful for these cases... I'm afraid the animation speed is hard-coded in the [interaction dialog here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/components/InteractionDialog.java#L377); it can't be changed back and forth.

Comment: I think the parent of `settingBtn` is the menu. Please refer to the component inspector hierarchy for `settingBtn` (marked with red) in the question.
How do I solve the second issue even if the first issue is solved? `isSideMenuShowing()` is useless for On-Boarding process.

Comment: The is showing method is working. I just posted test code.